# Antd rounded progress bar

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using this component https://ant.design/components/progress/ in the circle style. But the percentage number is showing out of the circle. Anyone knows why?

[image]

> `import { Progress } from "antd";`

```
 > <div className="overview-div">   <div className="bar-container">
    >     <div className="ab">
    >       <Progress
    >         type="circle"
    >         strokeColor={{
    >           "0%": "#108ee9",
    >           "100%": "#87d068",
    >         }}
    >         percent={25}
    >         width={150}
    >         trailColor="#333533"
    >       />
    >     </div>    
    >   </div>    </div>
```

Tha'ts the code, i've imported the progress bar and styled with the original properties

Comment: You're either missing or overwriting some styles. But it's hard to tell from a picture, which one it is.

Comment: can you share some code

Comment: Edited the post

Answer (score 0):

Did you import

```
import 'antd/dist/antd.css'; // or 'antd/dist/antd.less'
```

in your App.js file?

Comment: I did not, and when i did now, it worked, the problem is that every color changed. How can i specifiy it? I tried importing it to the component of the circle, but still every color changed

Comment: Without using antd css you probably used your custom style.
By importing now everything is probably override.
With every color, are you talking about the circle?

Comment: But how can i prevent it from changing the colors?

Comment: You can watch here https://ant.design/components/progress/#API all the props for the progress bar.
You need to use
`strokeColor` or `trailColor`for correctly change the color as you want